# How to restrict credentials in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have multiple users on a Jenkins server, each with their own credentials for external secured servers needed to run their builds. I am using the credentials plugin to manage the stored credentials. Currently, when a user configures a project, they can use anyones credentials for doing external jobs. I need to make it so that each user only sees the credentials they own when they configure jobs on the jenkins server. How would I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by each user only sees the credentials they own?

Comment: A user should only see credentials for an account they have access to. I don't want user a to be able to see password for user b when using stored credentials. Is this something I can do with credential domains? How would I go about this?

Comment: Where are you seeing the other credentials, in the administrative areas within Jenkins?

Comment: I am using the credentials plugin, if that helps. The credentials are not for Jenkins itself but for external secured servers. I want users to only be able to use credentials that they added themselves. If a user creates a project, right now all the added credentials for all users show up.

Comment: I am not sure whether that would be possible so unfortunately I am out of suggestions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [Folders plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin) allows to limit the scope of credentials to a specific folder.

If you're fine with restricting access of different users to different folders (e.g., with the [Role Strategy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin)), then this could be a solution.

Just create the folder, enter the folder, then select the "Credentials" link on the sidebar. A new link should appear called "Folder" click that and then define your credentials. Jobs in other folders will not be able to use those.

Comment: Correct answer.

Comment: @AlexO can you please explain a bit better how to limit the scope of a credential to a folder? I'm having the same issue and have all the Folders, Credentials and Role Strategy plugins installed and updated. Thanks.

Comment: Just create the folder, enter the folder, then select the "Credentials" link on the sidebar. A new link should appear called "Folder" click that and then define your credentials. Jobs in other folders will not be able to use those.

Comment: Thanks @AlexO. That worked. Finally I have some control over the use of credentials.